# Environment to create standalone web applications

Tags: python, web, template-engine

At my office we are trying to find the best envirnoment to build standalone web applications (HTML applications running on your own computer like a Desktop tool). The operation of this application would be:

- The user inserts input data in forms on several tabs (alphanumerical and files with time series)
- The program returns output data (alphanumerical info and graphs)

I had thought in an application with:

- Business logic in Python (I'm very familiar with this language)
- Template engine, in order to write once the HTML code
- HTML + JavaScript + CSS, to show output data and graphs, with REST philosophy if possible (the Business Logic would write several output JSON files)

I don't know if a environment/framework meeting these requirements exists. Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score -1):

Have you heard about Django? From the [docs](https://www.djangoproject.com/)...

*Django is a high-level Python Web framework that encourages rapid development and clean, pragmatic design.*

*Developed by a fast-moving online-news operation, Django was designed to handle two challenges: the intensive deadlines of a newsroom and the stringent requirements of the experienced Web developers who wrote it. It lets you build high-performing, elegant Web applications quickly.*
*Django focuses on automating as much as possible and adhering to the DRY principle.*

Comment: Hola Juanky. Thank you very much for your answer. Gracias malagueño! 

I've started to browse information about Django. It's very interesting the approach of this framework. 

I've got two questions: Can I create a lightweight HTTP server with Django and package the program to distribute it (e.g. in a Windows environment)? 

Regards.

Comment: Holaaaaa :) Do you want to develop a desktop app or a web app?? Django will be good for the second option, where the environment could be Windows, Linux, ... as your app will be accessed through a browser.

Comment: Yep, I want to create a web application (I'm very familiar creating web GUIs), but I'd like to distribute the application within my organization (Windows PCs) so that users can use it on their Desktop's web browsers. I don't like to maintain and manage a centralized web server, but sending one EXE file to these users.

I suppose that Django creates (on every user's PC) a lightweight HTTP server to draw the HTML pages, right? And I also suppose than (by using py2exe or similar) you can package the Python code to distribute it.

Gracias de nuevo :-)